# Insert or add a new column to empty dataframe does not work

Tags: pandas

When I add or insert a new column to empty DF , it does not work. It works otherwise .

```
>>> dfTemp=pd.DataFrame()
    >>> dfTemp
    Empty DataFrame
    Columns: []
    Index: []
    >>> dfTemp.insert(0, 'Company' , 'Apple')
    >>> dfTemp.insert(1, 'Device' , 'ipad')
    >>> dfTemp
    Empty DataFrame
    Columns: [Company, Device]
    Index: []
    >>> dfTemp = pd.DataFrame({"Year": [2017]})
    >>> dfTemp.insert(0, 'Company' , 'Apple')
    >>> dfTemp.insert(1, 'Device' , 'ipad')
    >>> dfTemp
      Company Device  Year
    0   Apple   ipad  2017

    >>> dfTemp = pd.DataFrame({"Year": [2017]})
    >>> dfTemp['Company']='Apple'
    >>> dfTemp['Device']='ipad'
    >>> dfTemp
       Year Company Device
    0  2017   Apple   ipad
   >>> dfTemp=pd.DataFrame()
   >>> dfTemp['Company']='Apple'
   >>> dfTemp['Device']='ipad'
   >>> dfTemp
   Empty DataFrame
   Columns: [Company, Device]
   Index: []
```

what is workaround to make it work for empty DF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insert` fails because the index label doesn't exist, so in your second example `dfTemp.insert(1, 'Device' , 'ipad')` this fails because `1` doesn't exist, but the previous row insertion worked fine.

For the other situations it's the same reason, you can do [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) using `loc` or `iloc`.

```
In[23]:
dfTemp.loc[0, 'Company']= 'apple'
dfTemp

Out[23]: 
  Company
0   apple
```

It looks like `.append` suits your use case better.

```
In[26]:
dfTemp = dfTemp.append({'Company':'apple', 'Year':2017}, ignore_index=True)
dfTemp

Out[26]: 
  Company    Year
0   apple  2017.0
```

Note that iteratively growing a df is non-performant